# Pattern lock screen on Froyo, what should I do if I forget the pass?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, lock-screens

What should I do if I forget the standard pattern lock screen order/pass (the one that you need to join 4 or more points between the 3x3 matrix screen) on my android phone?

Comment: Hmmm.. I had been using the pattern lock since I had this phone and only now realized I didn't see the usual gmail unlock that you usually can use if you forgot the pattern.

Comment: Does [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231867/216556) solves your problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have linked a gmail account on your android, dont worry.. just follow these steps:-

1. Input the wrong pattern 3 or more times till "forgot password" button appears
2. Click on forgot password button and check your inbox

Comment: It is not available in modern Android. Using it will only increase timeout.