# How to unlock device when I forgot my password?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lock-screens, security, password, locked-out

I've read [Recovering from forgotten lock pattern](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18008/recovering-from-forgotten-lock-pattern) which states that there is an option to disable the lock using my Google account information. However I did not noticed such an option when I entered my *password* five times wrong. (Although there was also a 20s or 30s delay to complicate brute force attacks.) I use Android 4.0.3 on a Asus Transformer Prime TF201.

Would factory reset work?

Comment: Why do you think, factory reset may not work? It wipes out every custom configurations..

Comment: As the device is locked I did not know if I could employ a factory reset. I just guess that there is a key-combination like: volume down + power button or something similar.. I was not sure.

Comment: Yes.. you can factory reset from recovery mode. How to enter this mode varies as per devices.

Comment: If you're just trying to remove the lock pattern then a factory reset would work, recovery mode is usually accessible by powering off the device and then pressing power+volume down until it boots into bootloader mode, from there up/down volume keys will get you to recovery where you can factory reset. but if you need access to the data that is behind the lock screen and you don't have root then you're practically out of luck unfortunately.

Comment: Factory reset will work. You can unlock the device remotely if you have some app installed for that, like the MIUI unlock service.

https://www.devicesfaq.com/en/reset/asus-transformer-prime-tf201

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always factory reset your device. Factory reset wipes out all custom configurations including PIN/Security Lock.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a factory reset will work.

First, you will need to boot into recovery mode, this is device-specific, so you will need to google how it's done on your phone. But on mine for example: hold power and volume up until a menu opens up, select recovery with volume up, press volume down, and when the "no command" screen opens up, press power and volume up.

Once you're inside recovery mode, select "factory reset" or "perform factory reset" with the volume buttons, and press the power button. Then select yes, and press the power button.

After the factory reset is completed, it will ask for your Google account credentials. If it asks for the previous password, tap "use Google account instead". If your device doesn't have a Google account or you don't know the password for it, look up your phone on hardreset.info and select "bypass frp" or "bypass factory reset protection".

Answer (score 0):

That depends. If you do not want to lose your previous data, I suggest using the Android bypass tools available, but it needs a subscription though. Or if you are thorough in your monthly backup, I suggest factory resetting your mobile which differs with each phone model.

I can give an example for the Samsung model.

1. Press the power button and lower part of the volume button simultaneously
2. When the screen blanks out, immediately stop pressing the lower volume button and press the upper half button with the power button.
3. It shows you the settings like reboot, restore, etc etc
4. For navigation, use volume buttons. For selecting, use the power button
5. Select the factory reset
6. Then select reboot

Tada! Then it asks for the password, just sign in with Google account instead.