# How can I reset a ViewSonic Viewpad 7 - "recovery mode" isn't working

Tags: factory-reset

A friend is getting rid of all his old geek stuff before emigrating, and he's given me a second-hand ViewSonic Viewpad 7 (Model VS13761). Problem is, it's locked and he can't remember the unlock pattern, so I want to reset the device to "factory mode" and start over.

I can get as far as the "enter Recovery mode" screen by powering it down, then holding down Volume Up + Volume Down whilst pressing Power - but it never gets any further, just sits there with a screen saying "enter Recovery mode" and a picture of some birds.

I've seen forum references to something called SUTL2 but Google hasn't turned up any more useful details. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the ADB usb debugging mode activated? It can be used to gain access. Else there's the password/screenlock recovery procedure (after a bunch of failed attempts). You need your friend to help you with this though.

Comment: Yes, USB debugging is enabled. Whatever that is... can you tell I know next to nothing about Android devices? :)

Comment: Fine. 3.2..1 hacked: there's p2p-adb's [antiguard](https://github.com/kosborn/p2p-adb/blob/master/AntiGuard/AntiGuard.apk) to do this. background [here](http://hak5.org/episodes/hak5-1205). You can install it using the Android SDK's *adb* binary (`adb install app.apk`)

Comment: you then need to launch the app manually: `adb shell am start -S io.kos.antiguard/.unlock` (or just download the whole p2p-adb package and run it)

Comment: Else, just go ahead and use adb to root it using one of the many exploits, e.g. [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1015005) (and then use p2p-adb to read the screen lock pattern). If that fails, let me know.

Comment: See also [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/16575) and [How to unlock device when I forgot my password?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20886/16575). Once you've unlocked the device, you can issue a factory-reset from the setup menu.