# I forgot my tablet PIN

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung, locked-out

I'm trying to log-in to my tablet, which I haven't been on in about 2 months. I can't remember my PIN. It's not giving me a chance to log-in with my Google account, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: I really doubt you've used a correct tag here.
If it's not a *samsung-galaxy-s*, then please update your question. Mentioning *correct* **tablet model** might help in receiving help.
<br>...As well as rebooting your device can.

Comment: [How to unlock device when I forgot my password?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20886)

Comment: [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847)

Answer (score 0):

Instructions:-

1. Download [Aroma File Manager](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1646108) latest version
2. Place it in the root of your sdcard(Preferred)
3. Reboot into recovery

4.
    *For CWM*:

Mount all partitions (including sd-ext if you have it)

And flash Aroma File Manager from sdcard

*For stock recovery*:

In stock recovery, there is no option to mount partitions, so

Flash Aroma File Manager, Click on menu option and go to settings

Select Mount All Partitions

Now, exit from Aroma File Manager and reflash it.

Now, you will see each partition is mounted
5. Now, go to /data/system

Note : If you have sd-ext mod to increase internal storage, go to /sd-ext/system/
6. Now, If you have to remove pattern lock, long press and delete gesture.key

If you want to remove password, delete password.key
If you want to remove gesture, delete gesture.key

1. Exit the Aroma File Manager
2. Reboot

Comment: I read that Aroma does not work on stock recovery. Does it?

Answer (score -1):

If you have not rooted your tablet just hard reset it.

Comment: I don't think it matters if you are rooted or not. You can do a factory restore either way.