# My Sony Xperia E4g is locked by android device manager and I can't

Tags: locked-out, android-device-manager

How do I unlock my phone if I've forgotten the password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unlock Google Device Manager remote lock?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/68687/how-to-unlock-google-device-manager-remote-lock)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unlock device when I forgot my password?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20886/how-to-unlock-device-when-i-forgot-my-password)

Answer (score -2):

You don't ... Factory reset is the only way I found, after I broke the screen in frustration. Yay.