# Forgot my Android Login Pattern

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, lock-screens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recovering from forgotten lock pattern](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18008/recovering-from-forgotten-lock-pattern)

I am using  Samsung Galaxy Y Duos S6102 i forgot my login pattern and there is no reset Option  on the screen. Is there any option to unlock it.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to unlock with your Google credentials after a number of failed unlock attempts. At that point, you will be prompted to enter username and password of the "master account" (i.e. the main Google account) this device was registered with. Entered correctly, it will then prompt you to define a new lock pattern.