# I forgot my lock pattern, how do I reset it?

Tags: security, lock-screens, locked-out

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recovering from forgotten lock pattern](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18008/recovering-from-forgotten-lock-pattern)

I have a Toshiba Thrive Android Table and I forgot what I used as my pattern lock. How do I reset it? Someone please help!

Comment: Please see these previous questions for more on unlocking a pattern-locked device: [Pattern lock screen on Froyo, what should I do if I forget the pass?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9851/) and [Recovering from forgotten lock pattern](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18008/)

Comment: Let us know if none of those work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Enter wrong pattern until you see "Forget Pattern?" button on bottom-right. Tap this button  and you'll get pattern reset instructions in your inbox (default email attached with default Google  Account will be used).
If there's no default Google Account attached with device, you'll need to factory reset your device from recovery mode. To save data in this case, create Nandroid backup of your device and restore using Titanium Backup app.